# Error during update to PHP 7.0 when currently on PHP 5.6

Tags: php, centos6

I have CentOS 6.7 installed with PHP 5.6 using remi repo. I want to upgrade to PHP 7.0 from remi and I already update the remi repo to enabled the PHP 7.0. And I install memcached 3.0.8.

I run this command.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php70 update
```

but this error appear

```
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-3.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
           Requires: php(api) = 20131106-64
           Removing: php-common-5.6.16-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Updated By: php-common-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               php(api) = 20151012-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-7.0.0-3.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               php(api) = 20151012-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-3.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Removing: php-common-5.6.16-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Updated By: php-common-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               php(zend-abi) = 20151012-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-7.0.0-3.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               php(zend-abi) = 20151012-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memcache extension is not yet compatible with PHP 7, so not available in remi repository, and so yum prevent the upgrade, which is expected.

If you can remove php-pecl-memcache, you will be able to upgrade.
If you really need it, you have to wait for a new version.

Compatibility and availability list, see: http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status

Comment: Oh Remi, I am suprised you answer this, that's great. Yes, now I am not experience error again when I run

`yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php70 update`

maybe because you already update it, thanks Remi, I appreciate your dedication on PHP and your repository

Comment: Yes, we have now a package (from git), but not an official release.

Comment: ic ic, so it means if the official release is released then it will replaced or how?

Comment: It will be updated (by yum update) to any stable / official version, when available.